# In pandas.plot, vlines() does not work well for string index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In a pandas.Dataframe with a string index, I am having trouble specifying the index (x-axis) when drawing a vertical auxiliary line.

The pandas.Dataframe I want to plot looks like below.
I have confirmed that the index type is object.

```
print(df_occ_test.index.dtype)

object

print(df_occ_test)

            a      b      c      d      e      f
p_time                                          
16:45   15.99  24.60  16.05  16.19  13.14  16.26
16:46   15.50  22.83  15.92  16.09  13.14  16.67
16:47   15.38  23.62  15.78  16.01  13.36  16.46
16:48   16.42  23.37  15.69  15.82  13.14  17.55
16:49   16.79  23.19  15.90  15.79  14.13  17.79
16:50   16.73  23.05  16.15  16.16  13.62  17.66
16:51   16.91  23.42  16.45  16.32  14.03  16.51
16:52   17.04  22.30  16.32  16.67  14.75  16.78
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Specifying ['17:00','17:30'] in as.vlines does not work well.

```py
ax = df_occ_test.plot(figsize=(8,5))

ax.vlines(['17:00','17:30'],ax.get_ylim()[0],ax.get_ylim()[1],colors='black',linestyles='dashed')

ax.legend(loc="lower right", bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, -0.3,), borderaxespad=0,ncol=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are plotting categorical (string) data, not time data. In this case, your plot uses integer indexing for the x-axis (0, 1, 2,...). So, we have to retrieve the row number of the dataframe for the values where we want to plot the axvlines:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#your test data
from io import StringIO
data1 = """
p_time             a      b      c      d      e      f                                         
16:45   15.99  24.60  16.05  16.19  13.14  16.26
16:46   15.50  22.83  15.92  16.09  13.14  16.67
16:47   15.38  23.62  15.78  16.01  13.36  16.46
16:48   16.42  23.37  15.69  15.82  13.14  17.55
16:49   16.79  23.19  15.90  15.79  14.13  17.79
16:50   16.73  23.05  16.15  16.16  13.62  17.66
16:51   16.91  23.42  16.45  16.32  14.03  16.51
16:52   17.04  22.30  16.32  16.67  14.75  16.78
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep = "\s{2,}", engine="python")
df_occ_test=df.set_index("p_time")

ax = df_occ_test.plot(figsize=(8,5))

idx_values = [df_occ_test.reset_index().index[df_occ_test.index == val][0] for val in ['16:47','16:51']]
ax.vlines(idx_values, ax.get_ylim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[1], colors='black', linestyles='dashed')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Preferentially, you would convert the index into dtype datetime, then you could use directly datetime values.